# Azure Bot Framework, QnA Maker API, How to get query text in QnA Dialogue

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

In QnA Maker API, when no result found, it returns some default message or we can change that message, But I want to run a function/method when no result fount. Below is the code.

```
public QnaDialog(): base(
        new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnaSubscriptionKey"], 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnaKnowledgebaseId"], "Hmm, I wasn't able to find any relevant content. Can you try asking in a different way? or try with typing help.", 0.5)))
    {
        //this is what i want to call, this is working but **i am not able to get query text here**
        SendEmail email = new SendEmail();
        email.SendEmailtoAdmin("Query_Text", "Email ID");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look to the QnaMakerDialog implementation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs#L119) on GitHub.

You will see that you have several options, the easier would be to override the `DefaultWaitNextMessageAsync` method which is called after Qna search.

```
protected virtual async Task DefaultWaitNextMessageAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
    {
        if (result.Answers.Count == 0)
        {
            // Here you have the query text in message.Text so:
            SendEmail email = new SendEmail();
            email.SendEmailtoAdmin(message.Text, "Email ID");
        }

        context.Done(true);
    }
```

Please note that if you want to avoid the message sent about no Qna found, you should override MessageReceivedAsync instead and change the code inside the block `if (sendDefaultMessageAndWait)`